# Victoria 2 Presidential Dictatorship to Monarchy

Tags: victoria-2

I'm playing as the USA right now, and I've already been taken over by reactionary rebels and currently have a presidential dictatorship. Is there any event or decision I can fire to get my Dictator become a King? I don't want any cheats, I already know I can fire a monarchy with event 23111.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to become a monarchy without cheats, is if your presidential dictatorship is toppled by a new band of reactionary rebels.

My best advice is to enact enough political and social reforms to make the reactionary rebels angry at you, which is kind of hard considering that reactionaries never support reforms and are the only ones allowed in your upper house.